# machine translation of HTML blocks

Tags: php, translation

Is there any API (like google translation api) in PHP which allows to translate HTML blocks and translate only text out of the html ?

Comment: what do you mean by HTML Blocks? is this the content between a pair of tags? Or the contents of a text box or textarea?

Comment: Sorry I had written the question in a poor way

Here is what I have to do

I have a block of html I want to translate it from one language to another using machine translation API.

if I use "babel fish" api to do this it strips off html tags and google translates the html tags as well which I don't want.

if there is no such API which allows me to transalte HTML blocks One thing  I can do is

HTML Block = >> <span>text1</span><span>text2</span>

parse it to have -
<span><? echo $token[1]?></span><span><?echo $token[2]?></span>

token[1] = text1 =>> MT =>trans1

how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's translation API will translate while maintaining HTML tags.

The API is documented [here](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/).  It has both a REST and WSDL interface.

I tend to use the WSDL interface with PHP's SoapClient library.  Here is some code to show you how to use it.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V1/SOAP.svc");

$params = array(
    'appId' => 'my_app_id', 
    'text' => '<p>This is a <b>test</b></p>', 
    'from' => 'en', 
    'to' => 'fr');

$translation = $client->translate($params);

var_dump($translation);
```

You'll need to register with Microsoft for your own application ID which you pass up with each request.  You can register [here](http://www.bing.com/developers/createapp.aspx).

I would advise against stripping out tags, translating and then re-inserting the tags.  Since you have no guarantee that word number and order is preserved in the translation it makes it very difficult to know where to place the tags in the translated text.  Better to have the MT engine handle the tags.

Comment: I'm very surprised I haven't seen the Microsoft Translator before, this looks really useful.

Comment: Yep. It doesn't seem to be promoted as widely as the Google service. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Could not get your question perfectly but if you are looking to get text out of html, sort of crawling text on a site, you need a php crawler script:

http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=708122

But if meant to strip html and get only text, you can use PHP's:

**[strip_tags function.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)**

But if you meant to get specific piece of text, you could use regular expressions:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

Follow these directions to translate your website into a different language.

1. Sign into Microsoft Azure Marketplace at https://datamarket.azure.com/home/.
2. Go to [www.aka.ms/TranslatorADM](http://www.aka.ms/TranslatorADM). On the 2,000,000 characters/month at $0.00/month, select **Update**. Agree to the terms and conditions.
3. At the bottom of the Microsoft Azure Marketplace page, under *Develop* select **Register your Application**. Complete the registration form.
4. Go to http://www.microsofttranslator.com/Widget.  Copy the HTML into a Web page, such as www.example.com/translation.html.  Also add some text to your translation.html page, such as "this is a test".

The Web page should have Microsoft's translator, which can be used to translate the page into a different language.

Answer (score -2):

Use [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), [PHP supports them](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php). [Regexlib](http://regexlib.com/) has a nice library of various pre-written regexes you can adapt.

Comment: 1. that was not the answer to his question 2. if you are saying create the api yourself, surely he should use a html parser.

Comment: don't parse html with regex please :) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html